# Using drawables instead of text for AlertDialog Buttons

Tags: android

I'm trying to set the Positive, Negative and Neutral buttons of an AlertDialog to drawables rather than text.

I've been successful thus far using this:

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
builder.setMessage("Are you sure you want to exit?")
.setPositiveButton("Save", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {...})
.setNeutralButton("Trash", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {...})
.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {...});

AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
alert.show();

Button button0 = alert.getButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE);
button0.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(this.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_menu_save), null, null, null);
button0.setText("");

Button button1 = alert.getButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_NEUTRAL);
button1.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(this.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_menu_delete), null, null, null);
button1.setText("");

Button button2 = alert.getButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_NEGATIVE);
button2.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(this.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_menu_close_clear_cancel), null, null, null);
button2.setText("");
```

This is a workaround though, because I'm really just erasing the text after the fact. My problem is that you can't seem to instantiate a button without setting some kind of text.

Setting "[blank_space]" from the beginning yields the same result with the image being pushed to the left. Setting null or "" in the same place draws the AlertDialog without the button at all. You can see how it pushes to the left in the picture here:

[image: picture]

Is there anyway to use pictures only? It would be much nicer than trying to handle translations for my simple situation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AlertDialog is deprecated. Consider using DialogFragments instead. You'll have much more control and reuse ability. [Here](http://android-developers.blogspot.dk/2012/05/using-dialogfragments.html) is a good google blog that demonstrated how to use it and customize it.

Comment: Thanks. I ended up using DialogFragments. Your link was very helpful. Just created a custom dialog and added the buttons to the layout. Now to figure out how to give them that same nice border as the +/n/- buttons...

Answer (score 1):

You have just  to create your own custom dialog!! You can specify your `ImageButton` in a layout, then create a dialog with that layout, you don't need to go near the positive, negative and neutral buttons. You can find [here](http://avianey.blogspot.com/2010/05/android-custom-dialog.html) a good tutorial just use ImageButton instead of Buttons in your custom layout.

Answer (score 1):

From android document,

```
setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(Drawable left, Drawable top, Drawable right, Drawable bottom)
Sets the Drawables (if any) to appear to the left of, above, to the right of, and below the text.
```

Since you put your image on the left, therefore the image will display on the left of the button. You may try to place it at top/bottom.

The other way is to create your custom layout with 3 ImageButtons, and set it to the alert by

```
builder.setView(customLayout);
```

Comment: Top and Bottom was a good idea, seems it just displaces it in the opposite direction again though. No biggie, will just create a custom Dialog. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code:

```
            LayoutInflater inflater=LayoutInflater.from(YourActivityName.this);
            View view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.buttton, null);
            AlertDialog.Builder builder=new AlertDialog.Builder(YourActivityName.this);
            builder.setView(view);
            builder.setTitle("Are you sure you want to exit?");
            Button posButton=(Button) view.findViewById(R.id.pos);
            Button neuButton=(Button) view.findViewById(R.id.neu);
            Button negButton=(Button) view.findViewById(R.id.neg);
            builder.create();
            builder.show();
```

inflate buttton xml file as below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <Button 
        android:id="@+id/pos"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher"/>
     <Button 
        android:id="@+id/neu"
         android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher"/>
      <Button 
        android:id="@+id/neg"
         android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher"/>


</LinearLayout>
```

And at the end you can give click events to the individuals.Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

```
   CustomDialog dialog = new Dialog(MyActivity.this);
                    dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

                                        dialog.setContentView(R.layout.login);

                    final EditText editTextEmailAddress = (EditText) dialog
                            .findViewById(R.id.editTextEmailAddress);
                    final EditText editTextPassword = (EditText) dialog
                            .findViewById(R.id.editTextPassword);

                    TextView txtViewForgetPswd = (TextView) dialog
                            .findViewById(R.id.txtViewForgetPswd);

                    txtViewForgetPswd.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View arg0) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                            // RETRIVE PASSWORD
                            dialog.dismiss();
                        }
                    });

                    ImageButton imgBtnSubmit = (ImageButton) dialog
                            .findViewById(R.id.imgBtnSubmit);
                    imgBtnSubmit.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View arg0) {
                            // CALL WEBSERVICE OR ASYNTASK TO LOG IN USER
                            String userName = editTextEmailAddress.getText()
                                    .toString();
                            String password = editTextPassword.getText().toString();

                            if (userName.equals("") && password.equals("")) {
                                Toast.makeText(BibleActivity.this,
                                        "Username or password cannot be empty.",
                                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            } else {
                                                            }

                        }
                    });

                    ImageButton imgBtnCancel = (ImageButton) dialog
                            .findViewById(R.id.imgBtnCancel);
                    imgBtnCancel.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View arg0) {
                            // CLOSE DIALOG HERE FROM CROSS BUTTON
                            dialog.dismiss();
                        }
                    });

                    ImageButton btnCancelCross = (ImageButton) dialog
                            .findViewById(R.id.btnCancelCross);
                    btnCancelCross.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View arg0) {
                            // CLOSE DIALOG HERE FROM CROSS BUTTON
                            dialog.dismiss();
                        }
                    });
                    dialog.show();
```

////XML LAYOUT "login"///

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="480dp"
    android:background="@drawable/mbc_login" >

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="45dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" >

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/btnCancelCross"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="right|center_vertical"
            android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
            android:background="@drawable/cross" >
        </ImageButton>
    </FrameLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtViewEmailLbl"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
        android:text="Email address"
        android:textColor="#000000" >
    </TextView>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editTextEmailAddress"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/txtViewEmailLbl"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:hint="example@eg.com"
        android:imeOptions="actionNext" >
    </EditText>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtViewPswdLbl"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editTextEmailAddress"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:text="Password"
        android:textColor="#000000" >
    </TextView>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editTextPassword"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/txtViewPswdLbl"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:hint="password123"
        android:imeOptions="actionNext"
        android:inputType="textPassword" >
    </EditText>

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tblRowSubmit"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editTextPassword"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_margin="10dp" >

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/imgBtnSubmit"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:background="@drawable/btn_submit" >
        </ImageButton>

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/imgBtnCancel"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/btn_cancel" >
        </ImageButton>
    </TableRow>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtViewForgetPswd"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tblRowSubmit"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:text=" Forget Password ? "
        android:textColor="#306EFF"
        android:textStyle="italic" >
    </TextView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: This can help you to make any kind of custom Alert Dialog as you have got the xml layout so you can render it according to your needs. Thanks